# Problems with setting up my minecraft server via external IP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

I tried various of things already, I wanted to make my server using my internet, but I couldn't get my friend to join it. I gave him my external IP and with or without putting port at the end worked. In theory the ports are forwarded, I tried multiple combinations and nothing worked.

This is my server.properties config:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Fri Jul 16 16:02:05 CEST 2021
spawn-protection=10
max-tick-time=60000
query.port=25565
generator-settings=
sync-chunk-writes=true
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
enforce-whitelist=false
gamemode=survival
broadcast-console-to-ops=true
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
text-filtering-config=
difficulty=normal
spawn-monsters=true
broadcast-rcon-to-ops=true
op-permission-level=4
pvp=true
entity-broadcast-range-percentage=100
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=default
hardcore=false
enable-status=true
enable-command-block=true
max-players=10
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
max-world-size=29999984
function-permission-level=2
rcon.port=25575
server-port=25565
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
rcon.password=
generate-structures=true
max-build-height=256
online-mode=false
level-seed=
use-native-transport=true
prevent-proxy-connections=false
enable-jmx-monitoring=false
enable-rcon=false
rate-limit=0
motd=I'm just a meeeeemmmeeeeer and I meemmmeeee my life.....awaayyyy....awaaay
```

If there is something more you'll need from me, ask in the comment, but i will be skeptical about showing my IP, because I don't want DoS threats out of curiosity.

Comment: AFAIK, everything looks good for the properties. Are you sure you're giving the correct IP? You say in theory your port is forwarded, but can you include an image of how that's configured? You can redact any info you don't want to show, but the way the port is configured is important for diagnosis.

Comment: this is one of the configs i tried, https://gyazo.com/1df0e881634ef05b27ca2ef48c990f10
if u can say what i should change, let me know :)

Comment: The port forward looks correct, I'd say ensure that the ip address you have listed is correct (and set to static if possible to avoid having issues in the future with dynamic local IPs). You could also need to configure the firewall on your hosted machine to allow connections from port 25565. Also try using this tool to check that the IP  you're providing is correct, it can also check ports as well. https://www.yougetsignal.com/what-is-my-ip-address/

Comment: welp, ill try! although will take a minute to find where do i do this in avg antivirus

Comment: Good luck, this page seems to have more info on AVG: https://support.avg.com/answers?id=9060N000000gPlpQAE

Comment: btw, if everything is correct, should i be able to log in onto the server with external IP on the same machine as the server is placed on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127579/discussion-between-regnegade-and-bart).

Comment: alright but i have to do something rq, so see u later

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple thing to know and to check according your internet config.
I give you a short checklist:

- Check on your local PC, that you server is running on the port you expect (Simpli try to connect on the same PC with "localhost" as target)
- Check if you have running any Firewalls on your local PC, that could block your port

  - you can try to connect from another PC in your local network to at least test if the port is open localy)
- Add port-forwarding in your router to your local pc
- Make your the IP you give to your friend is the real Internet-IP (you could use https://www.wieistmeineip.de/)

  - I recommend using IPv4, because IPv6 is very complicated to use for custom servers)

If thats all done, check if yout Port is reachable from "outside" you can use

https://api.mcsrvstat.us/1/YOUR-SERVER:YOUR-PORT

e.g. if your public ip is 1.2.3.4 open

https://api.mcsrvstat.us/1/1.2.3.4:25565

The response should something like this

```
{
  "online": true,
  "ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "port": 25565,
   // and more stuff
}
```

When your server is online (Important for you is `online: true`)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling firewall and see if your friend can join. Minecraft is safe to run when there's no firewall, in case you're wondering. If that doesn't work he can disable firewall and try to join.

Comment: the problem is, my friend cant help me at the moment, and im not gonna post my ip to someone i dont trust, also tried checking if the port is open on site, while my firewall on router and pc is off, still closed